# Formating data to show correct decimal places in data fram in r

Tags: r, export

I am importing a large data set containing both text and numeric fields from a .csv file into `R`.
When I open the data frame, I note that the numeric fields do not display numbers with decimal places.
I would like all the numeric fields to have 2 decimal places.

When I write the data to a csv file from `R` I also note that the data is being exported with no decimal places.
How can I export the data to csv and ensure that the numeric fields have 2 decimal places

To import the data I use the following code:

```
#IMPORT RAW DATA
data = import("C:/Users/Manfred Kuhn/Documents/Rwanda IFRS 9 Data/IFRS data sets/Final Data Sets/RWANDA_JUL19_FINAL_REMEDIATEDv6.csv", integer64= "double")
```

When I view the data using the command `View(data)`, I notice that the numeric fields are displayed without any decimal places.

I have used the following code to ensure display the data with decmials

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)
data

format(data$OS_BALANCE, digits=4, nsmall=2)
```

Both print the data with the correct number of decimals, but this is not displayed in the actual data frame. When I run `View(data)` the numeric fields still do not show decimal places

To export the data I use the following code

```
export(RWA_Cleansed_Data,"C:/Users/Manfred Kuhn/Documents/Rwanda IFRS 9 Data/RDQchecks/RWANDA_Jan2016_Jul2019_REMEDIATED_CLEANSED_with_flagsv1.csv")
```

The data is exported without any decimal places. How can I change this.

I would like the numeric fields in the data set called "data" that I have imported to show with 2 decimal places[image]

Comment: try read.xlsx("file_path") function from openxlsx package.